# Fill an Array With values from that array

Tags: javascript

For example I have

`this.clients.clientTypes = [10,20,30,40]`

`this.clients.clientInputs.length` has the desired length, let's say for this example `8` (this is always proportional with the types)

How do I fill the array `this.clients.clientTypes` so that I get `[10,20,30,40,10,20,30,40]`?

```
this.clients.clientTypes = Array(this.clients.clientInputs.length).fill(??)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly let me know this is what exactly you want.

```js
let array = [10, 20, 30, 40],
        len = 8,
        result = Array.from({length: len}).map((v, i) => array[i % array.length]);
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Krishna I did this.

```
for(let i = 0; i <= (this.clients.clientInputs.length - this.clients.clientTypes.length); i++) {
  this.clients.clientTypes.push(this.clients.clientTypes[i]);
}
```

Any better solution?

Comment: You can also use concat and slice method like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an array of given length, then populate the value from the initial array using the callback of `array#from`.

```js
const arr = [10, 20, 30, 40],
      newArr = Array.from({length: 8}, (v, i) => arr[i % arr.length]);
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate an array with the wanted length ([`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)) and map (the second parameter of `Array.from`) the values with the remainder operator for the index.

```js
var array = [10, 20, 30, 40],
    length = 8,
    result = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => array[i % array.length]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let i = 0, len = this.clients.clientTypes; i < this.clients.clientInputs.length; i++) {
  this.clients.clientTypes.push(types[i%len])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.clients.clientTypes.length = 0;
this.clients.clientTypes = this.clients.clientInputs;
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using logic something like below:

```js
let clientTypes = [10, 20, 30, 40];
let clientInputsLength = 10;
let result = []
for(let i = 0; i < clientInputsLength; i++) {
  result.push(clientTypes[i%clientTypes.length])
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use following function and call it wherever required

```
const push = (arr, length) => {
  if (arr.length === length) return arr;
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= (length/arr.length); i++){
    result.push(...arr);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply use the [JQuery function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/): $.merge

```
this.clients.clientTypes = [10,20,30,40];
$.merge(this.clients.clientTypes,this.clients.clientTypes);
console.log(this.clients.clientTypes);
```

Comment: Logic is wrong and there is no jQuery tag on the question either

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Array.reduce`:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(a.reduce(function(result, current) {
  result.push(current);
  return result;
}, a));
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce